# Rails: Having problems with follow and followed system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, relationship

This is the error I get

```
undefined method `followed_users?' for #<User:0x007fdadbf11e28>
```

Extracted source (around line #3):

```
1: <% unless current_user?(@user) %>
2:   <div id="follow_form">
3:   <% if current_user.followed_users?(@user) %>
4:     <%= render 'unfollow' %>
5:   <% else %>
6:     <%= render 'follow' %>
```

If I remove the question mark I get this error

```
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
```

Extracted source (around line #1):

```
1: <%= form_for current_user.relationships.find_by_followed_id(@user),
2:              html: { method: :delete },
3:              remote: true do |f| %>
4:   <div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Unfollow" %></div>
```

I am extremely confused here are my code for the

**user model**

```
has_many :microposts
has_many :relationships, foreign_key: "follower_id", dependent: :destroy
has_many :followed_users, through: :relationships, source: :followed
has_many :reverse_relationships, foreign_key: "followed_id",
                                 class_name:  "Relationship",
                                 dependent:   :destroy
has_many :followers, through: :reverse_relationships, source: :follower

def following?(other_user)
  relationships.find_by_followed_id(other_user.id)
end

def follow!(other_user)
  relationships.create!(followed_id: other_user.id)
end

def unfollow!(other_user)
  relationships.find_by_followed_id(other_user.id).destroy
end
```

**relationship model**

```
attr_accessible :followed_id

belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"

validates :follower_id, presence: true
validates :followed_id, presence: true
```

**user controller**

```
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @micropost = Micropost.new
    @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
```

**relationship controller**

```
  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:relationship][:followed_id])
    current_user.follow!(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end
  end

  def destroy
     @user = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
     current_user.unfollow!(@user)
     respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
     end
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't you just be using `if current_user.following?(@user)` instead of `if current_user.followed_users?(@user)` on line 3.

Comment: Wow thank you, I was learning off the rails tutorial and it was coded that way! Thank you for pointing this out

Comment: Cheers, I've just sent Michael Hartl an email to get him to fix it. Nice catch.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. This was the result of an over-zealous search-and-replace. It's fixed.